# Prove $\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{sin^2(by)}{y} dy = \frac{1}{4}ln(\frac{a^2+4b^2}{a^2})$

Tags: integration

Prove $\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{sin^2(by)}{y} dy = \frac{1}{4}ln(\frac{a^2+4b^2}{a^2})$

I don't know how to do this since integration by parts isn't going to work and neither is breaking down the sin^2 into 1-cos(2x). Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about exponential integrals ?

Comment: Use complex integration

Comment: If you don't know how to start a problem, you can include the context where you encountered it: what book? What course? What methods have you been looking at recently? This information helps others write more focused answers. Questions without context are often put "on hold" - you can improve the question at any time by editing it.

Comment: Actually, after differentiation under the integral, we can integrate by parts twice to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ay/b}\cos(2y)\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(a,b)=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{sin^2(by)}{y} dy$$
$$\frac{df}{da}=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} sin^2(by) dy$$
$$\frac{df}{da}=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{(e^{iby}-e^{-iby})^2}{-4} dy=
\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{e^{2iby}-2+e^{-2iby}}{-4} dy$$
$$\frac{df}{da}=-\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_0 e^{(-a+2ib)y}dy+\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay}dy-\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_0 e^{(-a-2ib)y}dy$$
$$\frac{df}{da}=\frac{1}{4(a-2ib)}-\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{4(a+2ib)}=\frac{a}{2(a^2-4b^2)}-\frac{1}{2a}$$
$$f(a,b)=\frac{1}{4}\ln(a^2+4b^2)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(a)+C$$
$f(a,b\to 0)=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay}b^2y dy=0 \;\to\; C=0$
$$f(a,b)=\int^\infty_0 e^{-ay} \frac{sin^2(by)}{y} dy=\frac{1}{4}\ln(a^2+4b^2)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(a)=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{a^2+4b^2}{a^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $a > 0$ so that the improper integral converges. We have

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\frac{\sin^2(by)}{y}\, dy = \int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\sin^2(by)\int_0^\infty e^{-sy}\, ds = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(a + s)y}\sin^2(by)\, dy\, ds.$$

The interchange of integrals is justified as $\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+s)y}\sin^2(by)\, dy$ converges uniformly in $s$. Indeed, $|e^{-(a + s)y}\sin^2(by)| \le e^{-ay}\sin^2(by)\le b^2y^2e^{-ay}$  and $\int_0^\infty b^2 y^2e^{-ay}\, dy < \infty$, so by the Weierstrass $M$-test, the improper integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-(a +s)y}\sin^2(by)\, dy$ converges uniformly in $s$.

Now

\begin{align}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a + s)y}\sin^2(by)\, dy &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a + s)y}(1 - \cos(2by))\, dy\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-(a + s)y}\, dy - \int_0^\infty e^{-(a + s)y}\cos(2by)\, dy\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a + s} - \frac{a + s}{(a + s)^2 + 4b^2}\right),
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}&\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{a + s} - \frac{a+s}{(a + s)^2 + 4b^2}\right)\, ds \\
&= \lim_{T\to \infty} \ln(a + s) - \frac{1}{2}\ln[(a + s)^2 + 4b^2]\bigg|_{s = 0}^T\\
&= \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\ln\left[\frac{(a + s)^2}{(a + s)^2 + 4b^2}\right]\bigg|_{s = 0}^T\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2 + 4b^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{a^2 + 4b^2}{a^2}\right)\\
\end{align}

Therefore

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\sin^2(by)\, dy \, ds = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{a^2 + 4b^2}{a^2}\right),$$

that is,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\frac{\sin^2(by)}{y}\, dy = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{a^2 + 4b^2}{a^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer using differentiation under the integral (similar to JJacquelin's answer). This approach might be a bit simpler

The substitution $y\mapsto y/b$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\frac{\sin^2(by)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y
=\int_0^\infty e^{-ay/b}\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}
$$
Then letting $\lambda=a/b$ and differentiating $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y
&=-\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}\sin^2(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}(1-\cos(2y))\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\frac1{2\lambda}+\frac12\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+4}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, re-integrating $(2)$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y}\frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y
=\frac14\log\left(\frac{\lambda^2+4}{\lambda^2}\right)\tag{3}
$$
and putting back $\lambda=a/b$ results in
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\frac{\sin^2(by)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y
=\frac14\log\left(\frac{a^2+4b^2}{a^2}\right)\tag{4}
$$